# RubyMine - ruby - what does [global] mean in rvm, should i use a global or non-global sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, rvm, global

When picking from a list of RVM versions, for many versions I see two versions, as in:

```
RVM:ruby-1.9.2-p180 [global]
```

plus also:

```
RVM:ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

Does it matter which I use?

Answer (score 1):

Global in this case applies to gemsets.  All gemsets under the installed 1.9.2-p180 version will be able to access gems installed to 1.9.2-p180@global.